# OpenCV's SVM outputs a high misclassification rate, when Matlab does classifies data correctly

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv, svm

I am currently working on a project which partly relies on OpenCV's Support Vector Machines (SVMs).

In this project, I consider a train database of 454 images, equally divided into two classes : blurred, or sharp. My aim is to determine whether an input image is blurred, according to a set of 16 descriptors adapted from the academic literature.

These descriptors are computed for all the images of the database. Then, I train a SVM with the obtained data to predict the blurredness of an image, using OpenCV's `train_auto` function. Besides, in order to check the relevance of the classification, I perform an algorithm of cross-validation on the train database : 80 % of the images are randomly picked up to train the SVM while the remaining 20 % are used to test it. Again, both train and test images are equally split into blurred and non blurred images.

Now, it happens that this SVM is not correctly trained. Indeed, the same label is attributed to all the images, leading to a misclassification rate of 50 %. I am now trying to find and unterstand the cause of this phenomenon, which is all the more surprising that, if I use the `fitcsvm` function with the same dataset in Matlab, this misclassification ratio drops to 10.05 %. So, a priori, the data *can* actually be separated by the SVM : but, for some reason, OpenCV cannot find the right parameters to tune and train the SVM.

My implementation is below :

```
int main() {
    // Reads descriptors
    // A [0 .. 226] : examples of descriptors for images of class 0 (blurred)
    // A [227 .. 453] : examples of descriptors for images of class 1 (sharp)
    Mat A = readData("data_train_16.txt");
    // Shuffles the indices
    std::vector<int> t;
    t.reserve(227);
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 227 ; i++) t.push_back(i);
    FisherYatesShuffle(t);
    // Selects 80 % of the indices to train a SVM
    int n = 0.8 * 227;
    trainData = Mat(2 * n, 16, CV_32F);
    for (int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++) {
        A.row(t[i]).copyTo(trainData.row(i));
        A.row(227 + t[i]).copyTo(trainData.row(i + n));
    }
    // So we have :
    // trainData [0 .. n - 1] : examples of descriptors for images of class 0
    // trainData [n .. 2 * n] : examples of descriptors for images of class 1
    labels = Mat(2 * n, 1, CV_32S, Scalar::all(0));
    labels.rowRange(0, n).setTo(0);
    labels.rowRange(n, 2 * n).setTo(1);
    // Trains the SVM
    CvSVM svm;
    svm.train_auto(trainData, labels, Mat(), Mat(), CvSVMParams());
    // Tests the SVM on the remaining 20% images
    int ok_0 = 0, ok_1 = 0;
    int terms = t.size() - n;
    for (int i = n ; i < t.size() ; i++) {
        Mat D;
        int answer;
        // Tests if a blurred image is marked as 'blurred' by the SVM
        A.row(t[i]).copyTo(D);
        answer = int(svm.predict(D));
        if (answer == 0) ok_0++;
        // Tests if a sharp image is marked as 'sharp' by the SVM
        A.row(227 + t[i]).copyTo(D);
        answer = int(svm.predict(D));
        if (answer == 1) ok_1++;
    }
    // Outputs some info
    CvSVMParams params = svm.get_params();
    std::cout << "SVM type : " << params.svm_type << ", kernel : " << params.kernel_type << std::endl;
    std::cout << "C : " << params.C << ", nu : " << params.nu << ", deg : " << params.degree << ", gamma : " << params.gamma << ", coef0 : " << params.coef0 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Class 0 : " << ok_0 << "/" << terms << " (" << 100.0f * float(ok_0) / float(terms) << " %), ";
    std::cout << "Class 1 : " << ok_1 << "/" << terms << " (" << 100.0f * float(ok_1) / float(terms) << " %)" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Total : " << 100.0f * float(ok_0 + ok_1) / float(2 * terms) << " %" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output :

```
SVM type : 100 [i.e. C_SVM], kernel : 2 [i.e. RBF]
C : 2.5, nu : 0, deg : 0, gamma : 0.50625, coef0 : 0
Class 0 : 0/46 (0 %), Class 1 : 46/46 (100 %)
```

Such a ratio leads me to think that, to be labelled as 0, a point should be very close to the existing points already marked as 0. So, instead of having a [well-trained SVM like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Toj92.png), I suspect the current situation to be similar to [that one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jc2tk.jpg). The two figures represent 2D SVMs trained with the same dataset (approximately, I just outputted them at different times). Blue dots represent points of the class 0, red dots, points of the class 1. In the second figure, you can see that, due to bad parameters for the SVM's kernel, we'll have the following situation : even if a point of class 0 (i.e. a blue point) falls near many other blue points, let's say in the bottom left corner of the figure, that point will be misclassified anyway since it will fall in the red zone, corresponding to class 1. This is not the case in the first figure, where the margins are correctly computed.

I think it's the same problem here. And it doesn't tell me why Matlab's `fitcsvm` succeeds in classifying the data, when OpenCV's `train_auto` doesn't.

I tried to :

- check the contents of the `trainData` and `labels` matrices : everything is normal
- normalize the data for each variable : no changes
- use `CvParamGrid` structures in the `train_auto` function, and set some parameters to fixed values by setting the parameter `step` to 0 : no changes
- change `params.term_crit` in `train_auto` and increase the number of iterations for OpenCV's optimization problem solver : no changes
- decrease the dimensionality of the data and use only 2 components : the algorithm works with a misclassification rate of approximately 16 or 17 % (I obtained a similar value with Matlab).

Do you have any advices, any trails to explain this strange behavior of my code ? Thanks you in advance !

_

[Edit] Minor changes (fixed some grammatical errors, added some extra explanations).

Comment: You use the default settings for `train_auto` with a RBF-Kernel. Do you use the default settings for `fitcsvm` as well?  Because [matlab](http://de.mathworks.com/help/stats/fitcsvm.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com) uses a linear Kernel by default... (Input Arguments -> KernelFunction) Maybe that is the difference.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, sir. I agree with you, but even when I specify the type of kernel in Matlab by typing `fitcsvm(Data(:,[1:16]),Targets(ind), 'KernelFunction','rbf', ...)`, I still get much better results than in OpenCV, with a misclassification rate of only 16%. Moreover, training OpenCV's SVM using a linear kernel still outputs very poor results.